# ASP.NET Client Side Validation Not Working for Entire App

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET 4 web forms app that has been in production for almost a year. All of a sudden, on the production server only (IIS 7) client side validation is not firing. Server-side validation fires just fine, but nothing on the client side. There is no difference in the code between the two. I've compared the generated HTML/JavaScript and there are no major differences either.

Anybody experience this? Some strange IIS setting that my server admin didn't tell me about?

Comment: So you can request the page from your production server and it's not different in any way? That sounds fishy. It sounds like some kind of javascript is not being emitted.

Comment: Correct. The only difference in the code is the viewstate variable (to be expected). Otherwise all of the javascript looks to be there. This is so bizarre I feel like I must be dreaming.

Comment: Either that or your browser is doing something differently, perhaps due to "where" the script is coming from.

Comment: I love answering my own questions. In any case, the problem is that the production server was not serving the ScriptResource.axd file properly (which generates all of the javascript for client-side validation). I blame it on plesk and its hijacking of handler mappings!